# no puedo convertir una respuesta en QJsonDocument

Tags: qt

Tengo este problema al consultar los datos de un `webService` básico en `Qt`.

Después de hacer una petición `GET` con `QNetworkAccesManager` y usar el método `readAll()` de `QNetworkReply`, estoy recibiendo esto:

```
array(2) {
  ["HOST"]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  ["authorization"]=>
  string(32) "c07e6adab2de7403a8afb8e7c25c7e3e"
}
{
    "estado": 1,
    "datos": [
        {
            "idContacto": "1",
            "primerNombre": "Pedro",
            "primerApellido": "Revelo",
            "telefono": "312090934",
            "correo": "james@mail.com",
            "idUsuario": "1"
        },
        {
            "idContacto": "2",
            "primerNombre": "francisco",
            "primerApellido": "franco",
            "telefono": "312090934",
            "correo": "frank@mail.com",
            "idUsuario": "1"
        },
        {
            "idContacto": "3",
            "primerNombre": "gabriel",
            "primerApellido": "salguedo",
            "telefono": "8788459",
            "correo": "gabri@correo",
            "idUsuario": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Este es el método que uso para recibir la respuesta:

```
if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
    QStringList nombre;
    QStringList correo;
    QStringList claveApi;
    QString strReply = (QString)reply->readAll();
    QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(strReply.toUtf8()); //AQUI NO HACE NADA
    QJsonObject jsonObject =jsonResponse.object();

    foreach (const QJsonValue & value, jsonObject) {
        QJsonObject obj = value.toObject();
        nombre.append(obj["nombre"].toString());
        correo.append(obj["correo"].toString());
        claveApi.append(obj["claveApi"].toString());
    }

    for(int i=0; i < nombre.length(); i++){
        ui->lineEdit_apikey->setText(claveApi[i]);
    }


    delete reply;
}
else {
    qDebug() << "Failure" <<reply->errorString();
    delete reply;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hola la manera en que lo resolvi fue eliminando las cabeceras que se incluian al inicio  solo declare un QBytearray arr = reply.read(368);
luego use el QString strReply = (QString) reply.readAll();
ahora ya puedo manipularlo como un QJsonDocument